# Applying Gauss law to a current carrying conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, gauss-law

Is Gauss law applicable to a current-carrying conductor or any special cases where the conductor is not apparently in electrostatic condition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It applies in all cases as long as you have a closed surface that is
$$\int_S E•da= q_{enc}/\epsilon$$
But is this equation useful in solving the problem? It is if there's sufficient evidence to show the the flux through any $da$ of the surface is constant in size and direction. Then it means
$$A_S E=q_{enc}/\epsilon$$
Like an imaginary cylindrical surface surrounding an infinite line/ cylinder/ thick/thin cylindrical shell in the center. Otherwise This law is still valid but useless in problem solving.

Comment: The magnetic flux thorough a hemisphere is a uniform magnetic field which is parallel to the axis of symmetry of the hemisphere is not that difficult to compute.

Comment: No hemispheres are different because you can see that due to asymmetry each point don't receive the same E field